# Boostrap 5 - 3 Column layout and text align right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am creating a profile page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
  <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.80.0">
  <title>Detailed View</title>

  <link rel="canonical" href="">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#7952b3">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="../css/t02-stockDetailView_style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <main class="container">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Library</li>
      </ol>
    </nav>


    <div class="text-center py-5 px-0">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 px-0">
          <div class="well well-sm">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/380x500" alt="" class="img-thumbnail" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <h4>
                  Bhaumik Patel</h4>
                <p>CEO of Apple Inc.</p>
                <small><cite title="San Francisco, USA">San Francisco, USA <i
                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">
                                </i></cite></small>
                <p>
                  <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i> email@example.com
                  <br/>
                  <i class="bi bi-globe"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com"> www.jquery2dotnet.com</a>
                  <br/>
                  <i class="bi bi-gift"></i> June 02, 1988</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <br>Last Trade: 12.March 2021
                <br>#Shares: 123.432
                <br>Type of Transaction: <span class="badge bg-danger">Buy</span>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row mt-3">

        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">test</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">test2</div>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>

  </main>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I would like to create the layout the following way:

[image]

I tried to split all columns up using `col-sm-4`, however the text still *glues* on the name profile box.

Any suggestions how to align the text right and also align the text inside on the right.

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: You have all of the upper content in one row that’s set to be half the screen wide (6 columns) ` <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 px-0">` If you set that div to col-12, it will always be the full width of the page and your col-sm-4 with the Last Trade info will be on the right.

Answer (score 4):

I've modified your example to match your desired screenshot (except with right-aligned transaction text):

[image: rendered output]

This is a summary of the changes:

1. Change the surrounding container to always be `col-12`: `<div class="col-12 px-0">`
2. Set the inner left div to `<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">`
3. Set the inner middle div to `<div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6 text-center text-sm-start">`

   - Mobile text will be center-aligned; `sm` and above will be left-aligned
4. Set the inner right div to `<div class="col-sm-3 text-center text-sm-end">`

   - Mobile text will be center-aligned; `sm` and above will be right-aligned (change to `text-sm-start` if you want this left-aligned)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
  <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.80.0">
  <title>Detailed View</title>

  <link rel="canonical" href="">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#7952b3">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="../css/t02-stockDetailView_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Library</li>
      </ol>
    </nav>

    <div class="text-center py-5 px-0">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="co-12 px-0">
          <div class="well well-sm">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/380x500" alt="" class="img-thumbnail" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6 text-center text-sm-start">
                <h4>Bhaumik Patel</h4>
                <p>CEO of Apple Inc.</p>
                <small>
                  <cite title="San Francisco, USA">San Francisco, USA <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i></cite>
                </small>
                <p>
                  <span class="d-block"><i class="bi bi-envelope"></i> email@example.com</span>
                  <span class="d-block"><i class="bi bi-globe"></i> <a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com">www.jquery2dotnet.com</a></span>
                  <span class="d-block"><i class="bi bi-gift"></i> June 02, 1988</span>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 text-center text-sm-end">
                <span class="d-block">Last Trade: 12.March 2021</span>
                <span class="d-block">#Shares: 123.432</span>
                <span class="d-block">Type of Transaction: <span class="badge bg-danger">Buy</span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row mt-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill px-0" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">test</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">test2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
  <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.80.0">
  <title>Detailed View</title>

  <link rel="canonical" href="">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#7952b3">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="../css/t02-stockDetailView_style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <main class="container">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Library</li>
      </ol>
    </nav>


    <div class="py-5 px-0">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12 px-0">
          <div class="well well-sm">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4 col-md-4">
                <img src="https://www.sanghibrushwares.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/wood-gallery-placeholder-5-380x500.jpg" alt="" class="img-thumbnail" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4 text-center">
                <h4>Bhaumik Patel</h4>
                <p>CEO of Apple Inc.</p>
                <small><cite title="San Francisco, USA">San Francisco, USA <i
                                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">
                                </i></cite></small>
                <p>
                  <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i> email@example.com
                  <br/>
                  <i class="bi bi-globe"></i><a href="http://www.jquery2dotnet.com"> www.jquery2dotnet.com</a>
                  <br/>
                  <i class="bi bi-gift"></i> June 02, 1988</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-start justify-content-end">
                <div>
                  <br>Last Trade: 12.March 2021
                  <br>#Shares: 123.432
                  <br>Type of Transaction: <span class="badge bg-danger">Buy</span>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row mt-3">

        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">test</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">test2</div>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>

  </main>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I hope this is what you're looking for. I have removed the parent columns definitions and modified the breakpoints of child columns too. I have also applied flex positioning to the last child row.